# Python text replace with for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am just trying to remove all datetime values...
but everytime it is going to the beginning and refreshing the text with the last value. How can i delete the all time values ?

My text file is hey.txt and this is the inside of it:

```
14:15
24:32
trying
42:56
1:42
for
testing
```

Code part:

```
import re
filename = "hey.txt"
text = open(filename).read()
n,i,c,x,=(0,0,0,0)
datetimes = []
for number in range(3600):
    n+=1
    b=str(n)
    if n<10:
        b = "0"+str(n)
    elif n==60:
        i+=1
        n=0 
    datetimes.append("%d:%s"%(i,b)) 
for word in datetimes:    
    matches = re.compile(word).finditer(text)
    for match in matches:
        z= match.group(0)
        print(z)
        if z==word:
            open("datetimes-doc.txt","w+").write(text.replace(z,""))
            c+=1
        elif z!=word:
            c+=1
        print("proccess:%d"%c)
```

and this is the my sending file datetimes-doc.txt

```
14:15
24:32
trying

1:42
for
testing
```

here is the some of output from console:

```
1:42
proccess:1
2:56
proccess:2
4:15
proccess:3
4:32
proccess:4
14:15
proccess:5
24:32
proccess:6
42:56
proccess:7
```

Comment: Why do you overwrite the file _at each iteration_?

Comment: i am a newbie is there a better way ?

Comment: If your file is all times, and you want to remove them, why not just delete the file.  If your file is *not* all datetimes, please provide an example to show what the other data looks like, in other words, an [mcve]

Comment: Need more information. The output shown is what you expected or the result of your code? Are you trying to remove the hours and minutes?

Comment: What are trying to accomplish?

Comment: i am trying to do datetimes remover with python, this is an example file .my file is too large .

Comment: Yes i am trying to remove the hours and minutes

Comment: @DYZ i dont think doing this isn't so hard. i think there is some mistaken in this line: open(filename,"w").write(text.replace(str(i)+":"+str(b),"")) it was worked for some string but for this didn't work i couldn't find the different between them.

Comment: @SanDiego can you write clearly what do you expect from the program? from your file `hey.txt` what do you want to remove?

Comment: @hadi k ,  I am trying to do a remover for all times in any text files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than a for loop, why not:

```
#read entire file's content 
with open('hey.txt') as f:
    content = f.read()

# find time and replace with empty string
new_content = re.sub(r'[0-5]*[0-9]:[0-5]*[0-9]\n','', content)

#write results into file
with open('hey2.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(new_content)
```